# Difference between Visual Studio launching an executable and launching it yourself?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I work on an application in C# 4.0 (VS2010), and I have a very strange situation. A bug is reported to me from all the team and I always fail to reproduce it, till one of the other developers told me to double-click the executable and follow the bug's scenario instead of launching it from VS2010.

After some research, I found that most of the comments on this problem are regarding uninitialized heap memory and the like, but in a C++ context. I know that C# produces an *error* rather than a warning if a variable is left uninitialized, so this is not the problem, most probably.

Both builds are the same on my machine and the users', and I now know that pressing *F5* (Start with debugging) doesn't produce the problem, while *Ctrl+F5* does. So the question is not the difference between both (other questions have already addressed that), but rather: how can attaching a debugger to a *C#* process affect its behavior?!

The code creates a connection over the network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So the question is: How can attaching a debugger to a C# process affect its behavior?!

In all kinds of ways. It affects JIT optimizations, garbage collection, timing (think race conditions), anything which explicitly tries to detect whether it's running in the debugger, and potentially the order and timing of type initialization.

If you can now reproduce it, I would start adding logging and see where that leads you - once you've worked out what the problem actually is, you may well find it's obvious why the debugger changes things.

Comment: Note that of the above-mentioned issues with running in the debugger, in my opinion the most likely cause of the bug is a race condition assuming that the code is not explicitly detecting that it is being run in a debugger. JIT optimisations and garbage collection issues would be more likely to manifest as a bug in the debug build and not in the the release build.

Comment: [@JonSkeet, @dotancohen] I was trying to work on this problem by producing message boxes along the lines of the problematic method. In my first trial, I produced a message box from the very first line of code. The problem never showed up again!! What can be the cause of this?? How can a message box make such a difference?!

Comment: @OmarOthman: *Very* easily - a message box is *very* invasive, in terms of radically affecting timing etc. I would suggest using less invasive logging... ideally only even touching the file system periodically, to reduce the impact on timing etc.

Comment: [@JonSkeet] I've taken your "timing" thing and just made a `Thread.Sleep(20);` at the beginning of method, and everything worked. It's my first time to see a "deterministic race condition"!! I've learned nothing about the actual problem... which is bad. Thanks for your help and speedy replies.

Comment: @OmarOthman: So it may not just be timing, but `MessageBox.Show` is still doing a *lot* compared with less invasive logging. So go back to being able to reproduce it, and delicately add logging, backtracking any time the problem goes away.